# Parse error. '}' expected when using dot notation with data layer variable data

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have an object that I have added to the datalayer that has an array in it. In a custom html tag (javascript), I can pull the data out just fine. And it is still a well formed object. But when I use the dot notation to access the array, Tag Manager gives the error

> Error at line 10, character 39: Parse error. '}' expected

Line 10 is the authData line below. And this happened when I click the **Preview** button to test the changes.

```
<script>
    var dlv = {{dlv - My-Variable}};
    var authData = { email: dlv.Items.0.Shipment.Address };
</script>
```

I have followed the steps in this post. https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/access-array-members-in-the-data-layer/

Comment: Neither line is valid JavaScript syntax. Using dot notation for array indexes is only supported in very specific contexts, not in a regular <script>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element in an index-dased array should be accessed using square bracket notation, like someArray[5]

```
 var authData = { email: dlv.Items[0].Shipment.Address };
```

And a variable can't have "-" in its' name, because it's confusing JavaScript, wheteher "-" should be treated as arithmetical operator or as a part of a variable name

```
 My-Variable
```

And the interpolation braces are used in JSX, not in JavaScript

```
 {{ }}
```

Comment: An object property may very well have `-` or space or other characters in its name that make accessing this property in the `.`-notation impossible. You can still access those with the `[]`-notation.